# latexmk difference between linux and windows

Tags: latexmk

I use Texlive and need to comple via tex>dvi>pdf using latexmk, suppress halt on error and enable synctex. The command

```
"latexmk -cd -e \"$dvipdf =\'dvipdfm %O -o %D %S\'; $latex=\'latex %O -synctex=1 -halt-on-error %S\'\" -pdfdvi -view=none "
```

works just fine in windows. However, the same command fails in linux, says error near '='. What needs to be changed?

Comment: why do you have `"` around it? Where are you running this? (It makes a difference whether you are running it directly on the command line, in a script, or...)

Comment: @cfr I want to use it in a python script with sublime text. However, I've tried running it directly in terminal without the `"` as `latexmk -cd -e \"$dvipdf =\'dvipdfm %O -o %D %S\'; $latex=\'latex %O -synctex=1 -halt-on-error %S\'\" -pdfdvi -view=none foo.tex` and the issue remains.

Comment: A quick look at `man latexmk` for the `-e` switch suggests that interoperability with nested quotes across unix/etc. and windows is not always so easy. (I can't help with suggestions for windows, unfortunately.)

Comment: @jon the command already works flawlessly on windows. I'll need to study the man page for linux.

Comment: Right: that's the point if you look at the man page: what works on windows might well *not* on *nix (and vice-versa) due to the complexity of the quoting involved.

Comment: Directly on the command line, maybe try `latexmk -cd -e '$dvipdf ="dvipdfm %O -o %D %S"; $latex="latex %O -synctex=1 -halt-on-error %S"' -pdfdvi -view=none foo.tex`. Or you might need to escape the `"`.

Comment: Assuming you have a full Python setup for your script, could you modify the script to detect which OS it's running under, and modify the latexmk command accordingly?